# How to begin writing tests for Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I'd like to write some unit tests for my Android app. But I find Android testing packages a little confusing. To be exact I want to to write a test that
1- mocks an EditText to contain a specific string.
2- unit test a code that does some simple manipulation of the string and returns the processed one.
I'm not sure where to start from and which base test class to use. Any ideas to get me started? I'm using Java/Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Creating and Running a Test Case](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html) ?

It describes the use of jUnit with Android. You can write your own customized Testcases using jUnit.

[Android+jUnit Example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-unit-testing-with-the-junit-testing-framework--mobile-421)